# Kernel of derivative (differential operator)

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

We define $S$ as follows :
$$S(\lambda,u)=u''(t)+\lambda u(t),\hspace{0.3cm} (\lambda,u)\in\mathbb R\times C_0^2([0,T],\mathbb R)$$
where
$$C_0^2([0,T],\mathbb R)=\{u\in C^2([0,T],\mathbb R)|u(0)=u(T)=0\}$$
We want to show that $S$ is differentiable and evaluate both $\partial_u S(\lambda,0)\phi$, and $Ker(\partial_u S(\lambda,0))$, where $\phi\in C_0^2([0,T],\mathbb R)$.

**My Attempt**

1. The differentiability : We look for the linear operator $L$
   $$S(\lambda,u+h)=(u+h)''(t)+\lambda(u+h)(t)$$
   $$=\underbrace{u''(t)+\lambda u(t)}_{S(\lambda,u)}+\underbrace{h''(t)}_{L(h)}+\underbrace{\lambda h(t)}_{o(\|h\|)}$$
   So there exists a linear operator $L$ and we have
   $$\partial_u S(\lambda,u)=u''(t)$$
   And so, $\forall\phi\in C_0^2([0,T],\mathbb R)$, $$\partial_u S(\lambda,0)\phi=u''(t)\phi(t)|_{u=0}=0$$
   I'm not sure whether I'm right. My problem here also extends to the evaluation of the Kernel.

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: $h$ is not a $o(\|h\|)$.

Comment: That would be $o(1)$. $o(f(h))$ is a quantity of the form $f(h)\varepsilon(h)$ with $\varepsilon(h) \to 0$ when $||h|| \to 0$.

Comment: @BrunoB I just realized what I did. Thank you !